# Strip tags from text in php

Tags: php, regex

I have some post_text, extracted from a phpbb database, but I only need some parts from it, all post_texts starts like this:

```
[centrar:fr5j2hqh][img:fr5j2hqh]http://pics.filmaffinity.com/Anna_Karenina-345500867-large.jpg[/img:fr5j2hqh][/centrar:fr5j2hqh]...........
```

I need to extract the url between the bbcodes (characters after centrar: and img: are different for the post_texts

How can I do it in php?

Comment: You mean only this string `http://pics.filmaffinity.com/Anna_Karenina-345500867-large.jpg`?

Comment: Yep, that's what he means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with:

```
$input  = '[centrar:fr5j2hqh][img:fr5j2hqh]http://pics.filmaffinity.com/Anna_Karenina-345500867-large.jpg[/img:fr5j2hqh][/centrar:fr5j2hqh]';

$output = strip_tags(str_replace(array('[', ']'), array('<', '>'), $input));
```

Comment: The problem is that my string contains a lot of info: [centrar:biv944tq][img:biv944tq]http://img600.imageshack.us/img600/5182/uch7.jpg[/img:biv944tq][/centrar:biv944tq] [b:biv944tq]Sinopsis:[/b:biv944tq] Clive (Adrien Brody) y Elsa (Sarah Polley)......  and I only need the first url and sometimes, there is some characters after [centrar:...... I need to remove all of them, I only want to printo only the url

Answer (score 1):

Use backreferences and capture groups:

```
preg_match_all('/\[(centrar:[a-z0-9]+)\]\[(img:[a-z0-9]+)\](.*?)\[\/\2\]\[\/\1\]/', $string, $matches);
```

then access `$matches[$i][3]` to grab the "urls" for all matches.

This is the only method that ensures the "urls" are wrapped in proper/matching/closing bbcode tags.

Answer (score 0):

Given that urls will consist of "[]" chars only in their encoded form, this should work -

```
<?php
$str = "[centrar:fr5j2hqh][img:fr5j2hqh]http://pics.filmaffinity.com/Anna_Karenina-345500867-large.jpg[/img:fr5j2hqh][/centrar:fr5j2hqh][centrar:fr5j2hqh][img:fr5j2hqh]http://pics.filmaffinity.com/some-random-pic-large.gif[/img:fasda][/centrar:fr5j2hqh]
";
$regexp = "/\]([^\[]+)\[/";
if(preg_match_all($regexp, $str, $matches)){
        var_dump($matches[1]);
}
/*
Output
  array
  0 => string 'http://pics.filmaffinity.com/Anna_Karenina-345500867-large.jpg' (length=62)
  1 => string 'http://pics.filmaffinity.com/some-random-pic-large.gif' (length=54)
*/
?>
```